# Android Studio shows every line in build.gradle.kts with red

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a multi module project with Hilt as dependency injection framework : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/Hilt-MultiModule-Cache

It was building fine with no error message until I updated my Android Studio to Chipmunk 2021.2.1 patch 1 in stable channel.

I can successfully build the project and install it on a device.

Now in all of my build.gradle.kts files, I receive errors, for instance on dependencies part, it shows following error warning :

`Cannot access 'java.lang.Comparable' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.api.Project'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies` and

`Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'org.gradle.api.Project'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`

If you clone the project, do you get the same errors? The reason I ask this is because maybe something is broken in my Android Studio.

Why is that and how to resolve it?

**Addenda**

I decided to report it here : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234737625

Comment: How is complaining about a broken project on GitHub a programming question?

Comment: I can build the project and install on a device, so it is not broken rather it is out-dated. My thought was maybe something is wrong with Gradle  dsl configuration in the project that I can not figure out.

Comment: any update on this? I have the same issue on 2021.3.1 Patch 1